# How can I store recorded data from the NEST simulator in a binary format?

Tags: python, nest-simulator

I am trying to write spikedetector data into .gdf files in binary format, but I cannot.

I am setting the `binary` param of the spikedetector to `True` (I checked it using `nest.GetStatus`) but files are written in ASCII:

```py
neurons = nest.Create('iaf_psc_alpha', 5)
sr = nest.Create('spike_recorder')
nest.Connect(neurons, sr)
sr.SetStatus({'binary': True})
```

I am using NEST 2.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for NEST 2.18 and 2.20 is misleading in this respect. The `binary` option has no effect (it sets the `ios::binary` flag when opening the file, but that has no significant consequences).

If you want to write spikes in binary format, you need to switch to NEST 3.0 and use the [sionlib recording backend](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0/models/recording_backend_sionlib.html) by setting the recorder's `record_to` property:

```py
neurons = nest.Create('iaf_psc_alpha', 5)
sr = nest.Create('spike_recorder')
nest.Connect(neurons, sr)
sr.SetStatus({'record_to': 'sionlib'})
```

A guide for [recording from simulations](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0/guides/record_from_simulations.html) is available in the docs.